# Eclispe project "locked"

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

I have been working on a struts project for a month now, with the IDE Eclipse JEE. So far, everything was good, but this afternoon it decided not to update my project anymore.

Before that, after modifying something, I went on my project, right click, Export and then I exported the whole project into a war file and copied the result in the proper directory on the server machine.

Now, even if I updated one of the java files, nothing changes between one update and another. I even tried to completely erase the content of a file (the one that manages the user login), exported it into a war file and the website was still functional.

The weird part is that if I modify a non java file (ex a JSP file) the modifications work and I can see the difference on the website.

My theory is that Eclipse caches the java files to accelerate the compilation, so that if a file was not modified it does not have to entirely compile it again. But for some reason it is completely broken.

Some more details about the problem: even if I intentionally write something wrong in a file and save it, the red marker that should appear next to the file name is not there (same for the yellow marker for the warnings). I also have a weird red exclamation point on my project name and I don't think that it was there before.

So, does anyone knows what is going on ? Did I accidentally lock my project ? I tried to relaunch eclipse, close and reopen the project, delete and recreate it, I even reinstalled Eclipse but nothing works.

Comment: inside your project there's usually a place where eclipse stores the compiled classes. Look for a folder called "bin" or "target" or something like that. Delete that. You should also be able to force eclipse to recompile everything via the build menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

Turns out that one of the libraries I set in the build path was missing (don't ask me why, the JAR is still there but whatever). After removing it from the build path (as I was not using it anyway), everything works fine again.